# embedded Android: xml file is empty after board shutdown

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an embedded android project and I'm facing a weird problem.
I'm saving values on xml config files (using the transform class). I'm sure that the save operation finished (but I have to handle the save not finished case later).

if I shutdown the board in the screen where the files are saved. After the next startup, the config files are empty!!!!

I tried FileWriter and FileOutputStream instead of the transform class (I, of course, closed the stream after use) but I'm facing the same problem.

I tried to use a backup file to avoid this issue: I write into a new file, then delete the original one and renamed the new one with the original name. this solution doesn't fix the problem!!
I tried another solution: I created a backup file. I saved into this one, and then I copied this one into the original one (without any deleting). after my test case, the two files are empty!!!!

I's really a weird problem!! does anyone faced the same issue on android or on another os? I saw that question too [content of XML file created by java app dissapears if computer is shut down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611503/content-of-xml-file-created-by-java-app-dissapears-if-computer-is-shut-down) and I think it's a the same issue.
Is this a java issue? any solutions?

Thank you for your help

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find the root cause. I think it's mostly related to the board than android. I find a turn around, I created the backup files into the private storage space /data/data/my.package.name (which is located in the Nand flash in my case) and when my application started, if the config file is empty, I use the backup file from the private storage.

Really a weird problem but my issue is solved.

Cheers